# Apply Event Listeners to buttons via for loop?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to apply event listeners to an array of buttons, as depicted below.  The console logging works just fine, but when I get to the `for` loop, the event listeners aren't added to the `button`s to function as intended.

I don't see my mistake, and any help would be appreciated.

```
<button onclick="" id="optContrastButton" data-style="contrast">reset</button>
```

---

```
String.prototype.capitalize = function() {
  return this.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + this.slice(1);
};

let buttons = document.getElementById('optWindow').getElementsByTagName('button');
console.log(buttons);
for(let b = 0; b < buttons.length; b++) {
  let data = buttons[b].dataset.style;
  console.log(data); // Data returned 'contrast' :: OKAY
  buttons[b].addEventListener('onclick', function() {
    document.querySelector('#innerWindow').style.webkitFilter = `${data}(1)`;
    let c = data.capitalize();
    console.log(`#opt${c}Range`); // No Data returned :: FAIL :(
    document.querySelector(`#opt${c}Range`).value = 1;
  });
}
```

Comment: onclick is empty... not sure if that's intentional.

Comment: It was.  Should I delete it?

Comment: no no , you've misunderstood my question

Comment: it's okay, nevermind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two modern vanilla JS methods for adding event listeners are the raw assignment:

```
el.onclick = function() {...} // note the prefix `on`
```

and using addEventListener:

```
el.addEventListener('click', function() {...}) // note: no `on` prefix!
```

You're mixing up the two and using the prefixed version (`onclick`) in addEventListener. So the fix: Change

```
buttons[b].addEventListener('onclick', function() {
```

to

```
buttons[b].addEventListener('click', function() {
```

Comment: Yep, that's the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Event names don't start with `on`. You need to listen for the `"click"` event, not the `"onclick"` event.